# Issue with React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React, and am trying to call a function which acts as a component, but returns two values, one called 'render' which just returns a component wrapped in a div, and another called sliderVal, which is an internal state value of that slider. Below is code from MySlider.js

```
function MySlider(props) {
  const [sliderVal, setSliderVal] = useState(1);

  return{ 
    render:(
    <div>

<Grid container justify = "center">
<Box sx={{ width: 250 }}>
      <Typography id="input-slider" gutterBottom>
        {props}
      </Typography>
      <Slider
  defaultValue={1}
  valueLabelDisplay="auto"
  step={1}
  value={sliderVal}
  marks
  min={1}
  max={10}
  onChange={(_, newValue) => setSliderVal(newValue)}
/>
    </Box>
    </Grid>
    </div>
  ),
  sliderVal
}
```

In my App.js, I am using the following code to render two sliders, and pass their values into another component.

```
  var {render, sliderVal} = MySlider("Number of Paragraphs");
  var {render1, sliderVal1} = MySlider("Number of Words");
```

The first one works just fine, I can use {render} to render the slider, and {sliderVal} to access its value and pass into another component. However the 2nd one does not work and nothing renders. When I console.log render1 and sliderVal1, they are both undefined. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd change to:

```
var {render:render1, sliderVal:sliderVal1} = MySlider("Number of Words");
```

Comment: The explanation why @Oleg 's answer works is that you have your return values as `render` and `sliderVal` . They are not returned as `render1` or `sliderVal1`. This is why the first de-structured one works, but not the second one. Here, you are de-structuring it as `render` and `sliderVal` and uses aliases to identify them. @user3207650